# ¿Como valido, desde un botón, que un formulario este todo correctamente con formValidation.io?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Tengo un formulario validado con formValidation.io y quiero capturar desde un botón que todo este validado correctamente.

Leo la api ([acá el enlace](http://formvalidation.io/api/#is-valid)) pero no encuentro como hacerlo funcionar, solo me lanza errores que no se reconoce esa función.

**Información agregada:**

```
        $('#form-crear').formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            button: {
                selector: '#Guardar',
                disabled: 'disabled'
            },
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                CrearNombre: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'El campo Nombre es requerido'
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 5,
                            max: 30,
                            message: 'El Nombre de 5 a 30 caracteres de largo'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            regexp: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
                            message: 'El Nombre solo puede contener letras'
                        },
                        remote: {
                            message: 'El Cargo ya esta registrado',
                            url: "cargos/comprobacionNuevo",  
                            type: "post",
                            data: {
                                valor: 'valor',
                                CrearNombre: 'CrearNombre'
                            },
                            async: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
            switch ($button.attr('id')) {
                case 'Guardar':
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
```

Dice que para obtener el error es con "isValid()", supongo que seria asi:

```
$(document).on('click', '#Guardar', function() {
    alert($('#form-crear').isValid());
}
```

Eso debería de volver un valor "true/false/null" segun leo en la API.

Lo que no entiendo es esta parte:

> Ensure that the validate() method is already called before calling this one.

Comment: ¿Puedes enseñar el código que tienes actualmente?

Comment: Listo, actualice la pregunta.

Comment: Lo que esa parte quiere decir es que antes de utilizar `isValid` debes haber llamado al método `validate()`. Algo que parece no haces en tu código.

Comment: no lo hago porque tampoco se como hacerlo, lo intente, pero donde lo haria? al final de la declaracion del formValidation?

Comment: segun lo que leo es: $(form).formValidation(options).formValidation('validate')

"validate" es el identificador del boton, y coloque el id de mi boton y me dice: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro chequea la solución :D

Comment: Genial. Tenía que haberlo puesto como respuesta :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la documentación del [plugin](http://formvalidation.io/) no especifican bien su uso, solo se me ocurrio intentar asi y funciona perfectamente.

```
$('#form-crear').data('formValidation').validate().isValid();
```

Esto envia:

> true: si todos los campos son válidos

> false: si hay un campo no válido

> null: si hay al menos un campo que aún no está validado o está siendo validado